# TypeScript re-definition of local variables

Tags: typescript

Is there any specific reason why the TypeScript compiler does not mark the following case as an error?

```
myFunction(len: number) {
    var len: number = 5;     // re-definition of local variable (name clash)
}
```

Another one:

```
myFunction() {
    var b: number = a;       // variable a is accessed before it is declared/initialized
    var a: number = 5;
}
```

I have encountered both situations at least two times when converting Javascript to TypeScript. Would have saved me hours of debugging if the compiler had warned me.

TypeScript 0.9.5

**EDIT:** Here's an example of some invalid TypeScript that the TypeScript compiler compiles to valid Javascript:

```
class MyClass {
    myFunction(myParam: number) {
        myParam = 'abc';
    }
}
```

If I save this in Visual Studio, TypeScript flags it as an error, but nonetheless compiles it to

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function (myParam) {
        myParam = 'abc';
    };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

I encounter such situations on a daily basis.

**EDIT 2:** Request filed: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2128

Comment: TypeScript is just a very lightweight type checker put on top of JavaScript. If you want a more capable syntax checker, why don't you switch to Dart?

Comment: Switching to Dart may be an option for those who really don't like Javascript. I like it though, I just want a lightweight type checker, so I go with TypeScript. And I hope that this type checker implements warnings for re-definitions of variables.

Comment: TypeScript will always compile to JavaScript if there are no syntax issues. So while your second example is a type error, there's no violation of the ECMA spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While confusing, neither of these cases are errors according to the EcmaScript specification. TypeScript isn’t a linting tool. Redeclaring a variable that is already declared is valid in EcmaScript (it’s a no-op), and variable declarations are hoisted so there is no way you can access a variable before it is declared.

The first one is the same as:

```ts
function myFunction(len: number) {
    len = 5;
}
```

The second one is the same as:

```ts
function myFunction() {
    var b: number, a: number;
    b = a;
    a = 5;
}
```

Comment: But couldn't the TypeScript folks just decide that they mark such a thing as an error? The compiler could still compile it, but it would appear in the error list. There are many occasions where the TypeScript compiler compiles invalid TypeScript to Javascript, but marks it as an error.

Comment: I can’t think offhand of anything that TypeScript emits an error on that is not a type system error, except when trying to use certain ES5 features in ES3 mode.

Comment: The example you provided is a type system error. You declared the type as `number`, the value is of type `string`, that’s a type error.

Comment: Yep I know it's a type error. It's an example of the TypeScript compiler flagging something as an error but compiling it anyway. You said you didn't know of such a case, so I wrote an example.

Comment: I said an example that *is not a type system error*. The one you provided is a type system error. I’d be happy to learn of a *non-type-system* error, I just don’t believe there is one, except for what I already mentioned.

Comment: Sorry now I see! But there you have it. Why not take the same route as with type system errors when it comes to local variable re-declarations.

Comment: BTW: most of the TypeScript errors I encounter on a daily basis are type system errors. The most part of TypeScript is just a type checker.

Comment: “The most part of TypeScript is just a type checker.” That is, in fact, the *entire* part of TypeScript. If you want linting, use [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint).

Comment: +1 alone for mentioning tslint, which is the answer to my question.