# Why is it not an error to redeclare a variable in a typescript declaration space?

Tags: typescript

From section 2.3 (Declarations) of the typescript language specifikation 1.0:

*Declarations introduce names in the declaration spaces to which they belong. It is an error to have two names with same spelling in the same declaration space. [...] The global module and each external or internal module has a declaration space for variables [...] Every declaration (whether local or exported) in a module contributes to one or more of these declaration spaces.*

Why is it not a typescript error to redeclare a variable, like this:

```
var myVariable:number = 10;
var myVariable:number = 11;
```

But a typescript error to redeclare a variable with different types, like this:

```
var myVariable:string = "ten";
var myVariable:number = 10; // Error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeScript re-definition of local variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342881/typescript-re-definition-of-local-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Because variables are "hoisted" in JavaScript, the two declarations are basically condensed into one, at the top of the scope. The redeclared variable behaves just as if you are just setting the value. It "makes sense" in the context of the JavaScript program, and the compiler can assume it is safe to let it compile. However, if you are declaring it as a different type it doesn't make sense and it is useful to have the compiler complain about it, since it is probably a mistake.

This page explains hoisting in more detail:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: Hi null! Thanks for responding. Don't know if I'm reading the spec right. The frase "It is an error to have two names with same spelling in the same declaration space." seemed to imply that it should not be valid typescript, even though it may make sense in javascript.

Comment: I see what you mean. It is confusing, but my interpretation was basically that because the variables are hoisted they are not really "two names" unless they have different types. JavaScript would ignore any type incompatibility because it is totally forgiving. Of course, TypeScript is so new that it may just be a bug or issue that has not been resolved. Maybe someone else can shed some more light on the subject...

Comment: Maybe this is what they mean:

var a = 10;
function a() {} // Error

Comment: I'd say they just let the first example through because it will "be ok in the end" because of hoisting. TypeScript doesn't want to remove itself too far from JavaScript, and you can still make the same assumptions. In a way, it's just like a shorthand (sometimes longhand) for JavaScript. I wonder which is more likely in this case... will they clarify the spec, or change the compiler so it emits an error?

Comment: I'll ask over at the typescript forum and we'll see :)

Comment: Good idea. Maybe post a link here?

Answer (score 2):

This one has an interesting history. Section 5.1 of the spec describes the behavior:

> Multiple declarations for the same variable name in the same declaration space are permitted, provided 
>   that each declaration associates the same type with the variable

This language in the spec is somewhat new. In an earlier version of TypeScript, it *was* an error to declare a variable twice in the same scope. In practice, this was incredibly annoying:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    /* do some stuff */
}
/*  ...do some other stuff ... */
 for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    /* now work with the other array */
}
```

Note that `i` is declared twice in the same scope (remember that `for` blocks in JavaScript do not introduce a new scope). This turns out to be a giant pain because every time you refactored code to move a loop from once place to another, you had to care about whether or not there was already a `var i` somewhere else in the function body.

Compounding the annoyance was a now-removed feature that warned you about using a var before its declaration, so even if you only *moved* a loop from the bottom of a function to the top, you would potentially introduce use-before-declaration errors.

Countless minutes were wasted adding and removing `var` keywords to no real effect.

This also helps solve the problem of multiple declaration files re-declaring the same variable.